# Jenkins Url changes when going to /jenkins/configureSecurity/

Tags: nginx, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have set up nginx as a reverse proxy for our jenkins server. Nginx is using `proxy_pass` to the jenkins server so it should just be forwarding the requests and responses.

When I go to `my.domain.com/jenkins` (hitting the nginx server) the url is fine. I can click on the url for each project and the url will still look like: `my.domain.com/jenkins/job/myProject/`. Even going to jenkins configure is fine.

**The problem:**
When I click on Configure Global Security the url changes to jenkin's sever IP. This wouldn't be such an issue but the Google Login Plugin is hitting it as well and my OAuth callbacks are set to hit the nginx server.

**What I've Done:**

- I have set the Jenkins URL in configure to be `my.domain.com/jenkins`
- Made sure the `JENKINS_ARGS` have the `--prefix=/jenkins`
- Restarted Jenkins after setting the url in the configuration.
- Verified `jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml` has the correct location

Any ideas or suggestions would be amazing! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was nginx and the way I was redirecting.
I was using:

```
location /jenkins/ {
    proxy_pass $scheme://ip.address.to.server:port;
}
```

But needed:

```
location /jenkins/ {
    proxy_pass $scheme://ip.address.to.server:port;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```